# Where should I execute query using ToList() - in DAL, BLL or in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

**I have project DAL, BLL and Web. Where should I execute query using ToList()?**

Right now I execute query using ToList() in controller - is it ok? For example - from the beginning:

DAL - my method in NotesRepository class:

```
public IQueryable<Notes> GetAllNotes()
{
    return context.Notes.Include(x => x.Comments).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate);
}
```

BLL - my method in NotesService class:

```
public IEnumerable<Notes> GetNotes()
{
    return _unitOfWork.NotesRepository.GetAllNotes();
}
```

Web - my action in controller (execution query using ToList()):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var notes = _notesService.GetNotes().ToList();

    return View(notes);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion, that's a data concern so the decision to call .ToList() should happen in the DAL. There may be a case to be made for flexibility to perhaps chain things together or refine the query, so you could justify putting the call in the BLL, but you build that flexibility into the DAL anyway and overall the DAL return data, not query objects.

Not that it ever happens in real life, but this also gives you more flexibility to swap out the DAL with some other data source (such as a web api). If you bleed IQueryable into your DAL, that is made harder and layer/tier encapsulation is broken.

I would not recommend letting IQueryable into the Controller.

Comment: thx - so ToList() in DAL and return IEnumerable not IQueryable - thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @cadmium, I also would do it in DAL not in Controller.

PS: I prefer to pass IEnumerable always as possible and only handle concrete List<> when you actually need it.

Comment: Why return IEnumerables when it is in fact a list? Someone could do another .ToList(). I always try to require the least-specific as input, and return the output as specific as possible.

Comment: @Maarten, in this example (with db access) I would pass IEnumerable because you can defer the work until the actual enumeration. 
Another reason it's because IEnumerable<> is a generic interface and List is the actual implementation. 

Suppose that for some reason, you need to change the return from List to Array, if the return type is a List, you need to change that signature to Array and the users that already consume that code will need too. 
If the signature is a Enumerable, you can change to array, and the consumers won't need to change it. 

But, as always, it depends on you needs.